# Selenium python: change default saving directory having Chrome profile

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I use Selenium ChromeDriver with python. I want to print the page as a PDF to a specific directory. I also want to use a profile for Chrome. The problem is: Chrome with profile always saves PDF's in a default Downloads directory. Could you help me to use a profile and also print as a PDF to a specific directory?

Here is the code, always prints to a default **Downloads** folder:

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


# Adding info about printing:

save_to = str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent)  # where I want to save a PDF
chrome_options: Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{
        "id": "Save as PDF",
        "origin": "local",
        "account": "",
    }],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2,
    "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False
}
prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings),
         'savefile.default_directory': save_to
         }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')


# Adding profile

chrome_profile_path = f"{os.curdir}/chrome_profiles/"
chrome_profile_name = "Profile 1"
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={chrome_profile_path}")
chrome_options.add_argument(f"profile-directory={chrome_profile_name}")


# Initialize the driver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver",
                          options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://www.blankwebsite.com/')
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

Everything together prints the PDF to the Downloads directory. But if I comment the part about adding profile

```
# chrome_profile_path = f"{os.curdir}/chrome_profiles/"
# chrome_profile_name = "Profile 1"
# chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={chrome_profile_path}")
# chrome_options.add_argument(f"profile-directory={chrome_profile_name}")
```

It prints to the current working directory. Could you help me with It?

On Ubuntu 20.04

On thing I noticed in Profile directory there is file chrome_profile/Profile 1/Preferences. It has a line

```
"savefile":{"default_directory":"/home/gelkin/Downloads"}
```

which automatically rewrite it back if I change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this:

```
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "DEFAULT PATH"}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
```

Comment: well when I add this line to prefs   "download.default_directory": save_to   it still saves to Downloads not to current folder